# VBA extract value from html table

Tags: html, vba, excel

i want to scrap the following html code to extract a value from one of "td" tags of "resultsTable"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6d2NM.jpg)

I tried to run vba code below but it does not work. I receive

> run-time error code '91'

```
Dim appIE As Object
Set appIE = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")

With appIE
.navigate "https://www.investing.com/stock-screener/?
 sp=country::5|sector::a|industry::a|equityType::a|exchange::a%3Ceq_market_cap;1"
.Visible = True
End With

Do While appIE.Busy
DoEvents
Loop

Set table = appIE.document.getElementById("resultsContainer").Children(1)

Set tbody = table.getElementsByTagName("tbody")(0)

trs = tbody.getElementsByTagName("tr")

Dim myvalue As String: myvalue = trs.Cells(3).innerText
appIE.Quit
Set appIE = Nothing

MsgBox myvalue
```

Comment: Which line causes the error?

Comment: Hi Andy the line is "Dim myvalue As String: myvalue = trs.Cells(3).innerText"

Comment: Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

You aren't allowing the page time to load. Waiting for `.Busy` to complete does not mean that the page is loaded and page elements are available.

Here is one way to pause for some relevant content to be available:

```
trs = tbody.getElementsByTagName("tr")

Do While trs Is Nothing
    DoEvents
    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:02")
    trs = tbody.getElementsByTagName("tr")
Loop
```

Comment: Great! Now code works well. Thank you very much for your support!